# Removing matching content in a json using Powershell

Tags: powershell

In the json I want to delete a part everything inside the dependsOn and expecting to get dependsOn[],

```
"dependsOn": [
    {
        "activity": "WaitFor1Hour30Mins",
        "dependencyConditions": [
            "Succeeded"
        ]
    }
],
```

One of the way I tried is below

```bsh
(get-content -raw -path Filename.json) -replace "(?ms)(""activity"": ""WaitFor1Hour30Mins"",)(.*?""dependencyConditions"": \[)(.*?""Succeeded"")(.*?\])(.*?\})", " " | Set-Content Filename.json
```

It deletes everything except `{` but I am unable to neither match the starting curly brace nor able to delete it

Please share your ideas. or other way to tackle in powershell.

Comment: I think that a better way, would be to convert your JSON to an object, then to handle your object, and convert back to JSON.  If you give your JSON, I can try to show you.

Comment: [Filename.json](https://github.com/tushmesh/ecsdemo-platform/blob/master/Filename.json) 
I have included only part of the full (ARM) json. from line 11 to 16 I am expecting to get it removed.

Comment: Can you please help here ?

Comment: Please give a full valid JSON File. The one you give is truncated.

Comment: Updated the ARM template Filename.json

Answer (score 1):

As JPBlanc suggest, it's better to let Powershell do the work for you.

json file :

```
{
"dependsOff": [
                            {
                                "activity": "WaitFor1Hour30Mins",
                                "dependencyConditions": [
                                    "Succeeded"
                                ]
                            }
],
"dependsOn": [
                            {
                                "activity": "WaitFor1Hour30Mins",
                                "dependencyConditions": [
                                    "Succeeded"
                                ]
                            }
]
}
```

Sample Code

```
$json = (get-content -raw -path Filename.json) | ConvertFrom-Json
$json.dependsOn = @()
$json | ConvertTo-Json
```

Generate

```
{
    "dependsOff":  [
                       {
                           "activity":  "WaitFor1Hour30Mins",
                           "dependencyConditions":  "Succeeded"
                       }
                   ],
    "dependsOn":  [

                  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank You for your reply. 
I m getting below error 

Exception setting "dependsOn": "The property 'dependsOn' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property
exists and can be set."
At line:1 char:1
+ $json.dependsOn = @()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting

Comment: I tried with following :
 $get_content=Get-Content .\ARMTemplateForFactory.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$get_content.resources | where {$_.name -eq '[concat(parameters(''factoryName''), ''/LIVE_PIPE'')]'} | foreach{$_.dependsOn=@()}
$get_content | ConvertTo-Json

But the converted json is not in actual json form.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try :

```
$json = (get-content -raw -path Filename.json) | ConvertFrom-Json
$json.resources.properties.activities | where {$_.dependsOn } | % {$_.dependsOn = @()}
$json | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 7 | Set-Content  d:\temp\FilenameAfter.json
```

Comment: This scenario is working but in ARMtemplate there are multiple "$json.resources.properties.activities" are present by the above it is cleaning all other values as well ( which is not required ). Need to specifically deletes only when   $json.resources.name  matches "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/XYZ')]"